# How to show that if $X$ is measurable w.r.t $\sigma(Y)$ iff $\sigma(X) \subset \sigma(Y)$?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

How to show that if $X$ is measurable w.r.t $\sigma(Y)$ iff $\sigma(X) \subset \sigma(Y)$?

The given question in the book is

Suppose that $X$ is measurable w.r.t the $\sigma$-field $F$ iff $\sigma(X) \subset F$. Show that $X$ is measurable w.r.t $\sigma(Y)$ iff $\sigma(X) \subset \sigma(Y)$?

Can I use **"$X$ is measurable w.r.t the $\sigma$-field $F$ iff $\sigma(X) \subset F$"** to prove the given question by replacing $F$ with $\sigma(Y)$?

Comment: Sorry, your question doesn’t seem to be grammatical to the extent that I do not understand your intention. Could you reread it and, I hope, edit it?

Comment: I mean, why not? How is $\sigma(Y)$ different from any other sigma field?

Comment: For simplicity assume that  $X$ and $Y$ are real valued. Since $X\in\sigma(Y)$, then $X=h(Y)$ for some measurable function $h$. Since any $Z\in\sigma(X)$ is also of the form $Z=g(X)$ for some measurable function, then $Z=g(h(Y))$; i.e. $Z\in\sigma(Y)$. I leave the details to you.

Comment: That's really a question that kind of needs to be answered by whoever assigned the problem, but it's not particularly difficult to prove directly.  Just think about the definition of $\sigma(X)$: it's the smallest $\sigma$-algebra with respect to which $X$ is measurable.